# Creating a similarity matrix with jagged arrays

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

i have a dataframe as such.

| id | action | enc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | run,swim,walk | 1,2,3 |
| Cell 2 | swim,climb,surf,gym | 2,4,5,6 |
| Cell 3 | jog,run] | 7,1 |

This table goes on for roughly 30k rows. After gathering all these actions, and encoding with labelencoder.

I want to create a similarity matrix that i can use for clustering the cells with similar actions together.

i tried using `pairwise_distances(df['enc'],metric='jaccard')` but had a setting array element error. Padding it doesnt make much sense to me either.

Is there any way to generate a similarity matrix based on jaccard? thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the format of `df['enc']`? Strings? Lists? What is the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')`?

Comment: @mozway its a list

Comment: ok then you should use `s = df['enc'].apply(set)` in my answer and not `s = df['enc'].str.split(',').apply(set)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1, here is your dataFrame**

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [['Cell 1', ['run','swim','walk'], [1,2,3]], ['Cell 2', ['swim','climb','surf','gym'], [2,4,5,6]], ['Cell 3', ['jog','run'], [7,1]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'action', 'label_encoder'])
print(df)
```

or

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [['Cell 1', 'run,swim,walk', '1,2,3'], ['Cell 2', 'swim,climb,surf,gym', '2,4,5,6'], ['Cell 3', 'jog,run', '7,1']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'action', 'label_encoder'])
df['action'] = df['action'].str.split(',')
df['label_encoder'] = df['label_encoder'].str.split(',')
print(df)
```

```
     id       action                      label_encoder
0   Cell 1  [run, swim, walk]           [1, 2, 3]
1   Cell 2  [swim, climb, surf, gym]    [2, 4, 5, 6]
2   Cell 3  [jog, run]                  [7, 1]
```

**Step 2, add one_hot list as a new column**

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

one_hot = mlb.fit_transform(df['label_encoder'])

# add one_hot list as a new column
df['label_encoder_one_hot'] = list(one_hot)
print(df)
```

```
       id                    action  labelen_coder  label_encoder_one_hot
0  Cell 1         [run, swim, walk]     [1, 2, 3]  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1  Cell 2  [swim, climb, surf, gym]  [2, 4, 5, 6]  [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
2  Cell 3                [jog, run]        [7, 1]  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

**Step 3, generate the similarity matrix based on Jaccard**

```py
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
import numpy as np

similarity_matrix = np.zeros((len(df), len(df)))

for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
        similarity = jaccard_score(df['label_encoder_one_hot'][i], df['label_encoder_one_hot'][j])
        similarity_matrix[i,j] = similarity
        similarity_matrix[j,i] = similarity

print(similarity_matrix)
```

```
[[0.         0.16666667 0.25      ]
 [0.16666667 0.         0.        ]
 [0.25       0.         0.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with python `set` operations to only compute the Jaccard index on unique pairs of items, and [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to reshape to a square matrix:

```
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

# convert each "1,2,3" string to python set {'1', '2', '3'}
s = df['enc'].str.split(',').apply(set)

# compute Jaccard index len(a&b)/len(a|b)
tmp = [len(a&b)/len(a|b) for a,b in combinations(s, 2)]
# [0.16666666666666666, 0.25, 0.0]

idx = df['id'].tolist()

# convert back to squareform and DataFrame
out = pd.DataFrame(squareform(tmp), index=idx, columns=idx)
```

*NB. I'm assuming strings, if you have lists in `enc` replace `s = df['enc'].str.split(',').apply(set)` by `s = df['enc'].apply(set)`.*

Output:

```
          Cell 1    Cell 2   Cell 3 
Cell 1   0.000000  0.166667     0.25
Cell 2   0.166667  0.000000     0.00
Cell 3   0.250000  0.000000     0.00
```